# OpenAPI 3 Add RequestBody between parameters

Tags: parameters, swagger, openapi

I'm wondering if it's possible to add the RequestBody of an OpenAPI 3.0.1 file between two query parameters. I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.x, `RequestBody` and `Parameters` (query, header, etc) are in different sections. For example:

```
  parameters:
    - name: petId
      in: path
      description: ID of pet to return
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
    - name: petType
      in: query
      description: type of food
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: status
      in: query
      description: status
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: sessionId
      in: cookie
      description: session id
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: token
      in: header
      description: status
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
  requestBody:
    description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      application/xml:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    required: true
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/blob/master/src/test/resources/3_0_0/petstore.yaml#L244-L285

so I do not understand what you mean by adding `RequestBody` between 2 query parameters.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if it was possible to define a couple of parameters, define RequestBody and define other parameters afterwards.